# IE9: Object doesn't support the property "is"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to write a little jQuery plugin but I've problems with (of course) Internet Explorer 9.

This is the code:

```
$.fn.mytest = $.mytest = function() {
        if ( !! this && this.call && this.apply) {
            self = $("a");
        } else {
            self = this;
        }

    if(self.is(".stupid")) { 
        alert("yes, it's stupid");
    } else{
        alert("no, maybe you are");
    }
    return this;
};

$.mytest();
$("a").mytest();
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Abb6a/1/

On Google Chrome everything works fine, in IE9 it says that **`the object does not supports the property or the method "is"`**.

Looks like IE9 doesn't like the standalone version of my plugin and has troubles with the passed argument `this`.

How can I solve this trouble?

Comment: Put `console.log(this)` in the function and see what it shows when you use the standalone version.

Comment: i approve of the practicality of this extension.. you should publish it when you're done!... ha

Comment: You need to use `var` to create your local variables.  `var self;`.

Answer (score 4):

`self` is a property of `window` object, and it's read-only in some versions of IE. To fix the problem, just rename your variable. Or if it's purposed to be used in a particular function scope only, you can declare it with `var`.

Looks like all properties of `window` referring a window object like `top`, `parent`, `frames*`, `self`, `frameElement*`... are read-only in IE. Though `self` can be overridden in IE>9.

`*` = `frames` is a HTMLCollection, `frameElement` refers to `HTML(I)frameElement`, both of these actually contain window object(s).

Comment: Wow, I didnt know that. You saved me hours (of future project)

Comment: thanks I will test it tomorrow when I've Windows 7 available.

Comment: Just tested, the error is on  `this.is()` not on  `self`, even changing the name of the variable `self` the result is the same... **error**, if I test  `self` it works, if I directly test `this` it doesn't